# Jquery Ajax responce not working in safari..but other browser it is work fine..what is mistake here?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php?action=wordFind&word='+arrString,
        cache: true,
        type: "GET",
        success:function(res){
              if(res=="find") { }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What you mean by not working.Can you be specific?

Comment: first of all check if there is request to ajax.php. second step try to console.log(res) to see if there is responce object. you will find the issue after.

Comment: 'NOT WORKING' Do you get any console error?

Comment: other browser set result properly after result success but safari can't do this..after success i am doing another process..

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem? What more code do you other then what you've already posted?

Comment: @umesh chakor Provide a more extended question / code / error. Danger of being downvoted / closed. This way of phrasing questions does not benefit the whole programmer community

Comment: do you get result in alert(res); in your success function ..?

Comment: @netadictos i have problem thats why i asked you sorry to say but i am to frusted..

Comment: can i put my online link to checking stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php?action=wordFind&word='+arrString,
        cache: true,
        async:false,
        dataType:html,//If the response is json replace it with "json"
        type: "GET",
        success:function(res){
           console.log(res);//To check you are getting any reponse
           if(res=="find")
               {
                //Do the stuff you want.
               }
            }
    });
```

Comment: can i give you my online link for checking stuff?

Comment: Not necessary umesh-chakor